# Move Controls Location Dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a very simple app where have 4 radio buttons and check boxes like below image:

[image]

The radio buttons position will be triggered when one of the check boxes is checked.

Example: RadioButton1 is on position 40, 40, and the radioButton2 is on position 100, 40.. When the first check box is checked (checkBox1), then the RadioButton1 will be disappear and the radioButton2 will be take the RadioButton1's position and so the rest of the radio buttons.

Please have a look at image below:

[image]

And here is the code that I am using:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                radioButton1.Visible = false;

                radioButton2.Location = new Point(57, 40);

                radioButton3.Location = new Point(242, 40);

                radioButton4.Location = new Point(435, 40);
            }

            else
            {
                radioButton1.Visible = true;

                radioButton1.Location = new Point(57, 40);

                radioButton2.Location = new Point(242, 40);

                radioButton3.Location = new Point(435, 40);

                radioButton4.Location = new Point(619, 40);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I modify the position of radioButtons in hard-coded way.

My question is: How do I can make it the positions of the radio buttons dynamic? So when the radioButton1 is disappear, then the radioButton2 will take place of radioButton1's position and so the rest by itself, not by the hard-coded way.

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: you can start with `radioButton2.Location = radioButton1.Location` etc'...

Comment: This question could do with a  healthy dose of "why".  This seems like a very clunky UI design, so without knowing why you're doing it, my first thought is "don't".

Comment: If you're not bound to WinForms it might be worth looking into WPF and using a `StackPanel` in addition with `Visibility` properties.

Comment: I'm not sure if they have a free version, but the DevExpress library has a LayoutControl which will dynamically move controls within it based on the container's visibility. So if you hide one item, the next one will "collapse" into its place. That might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the checkboxes in a panel and set each checkbox's Dock property to 'Left'.

Then, switching the Visible property of each checkbox will cause the other checkboxes to 'slide' left or right.

And you would need a separate panel for the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

That sort of interface is very bad practice as users expect controls to stay where they are.
i would suggest disabling the control not moving it

that said if you do the following then it should work

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.Visible = !checkBox1.Checked;
    LayoutRadioButtons();
}

private void LayoutRadioButtons()
{
    var rbs = new RadioButton[]{radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3,radioButton4};
    location = 50;
    foreach(var rb in rbs)
    {
        if(rb.Visible)
        {
            rb .Location = new Point(location , 40);
            location += 50 //or += rb .Width if you aren't using same sized buttons
        }
    }
}
```